# Changing the distribution of a series of numbers with a power function

Tags: math, statistics

I'm trying to use a power function to change the distribution of a series of values between 0 and 1 such that the mean is 0.5.

ie. for each of the values in the series:

```
new_value = old_value ^ x
```

Where x is some number.

Is there a simple way to calculate the value of x?

Comment: have a look on how to transform pdf's. Here is one [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14490/172803), see if you can get your `x` from that. (BTW...not the best choice calling it `x`)

Answer (score 0):

You could run an [optimizer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root_scalar.html#scipy.optimize.root_scalar) from Python's [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/).

Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

values = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 5)
sol = optimize.root_scalar(lambda pwr: np.mean(values ** pwr) - 0.5,
                           bracket=[np.log(0.5) / np.log(values.max()), np.log(0.5) / np.log(values.min())])

print('given values:', values)
print('given mean:', values.mean())
print('power:', sol.root)
print('transformed values:', values ** sol.root)
print('mean of transformed values:', (values ** sol.root).mean())
```

Example output:

```py
given values: [0.82082056 0.01531309 0.56587417 0.53283897 0.73051697]
given mean: 0.5330727532243068
power: 1.1562709936704882
transformed values: [0.79588022 0.00796968 0.5176988  0.48291519 0.69553611]
mean of transformed values: 0.5
```

A much simplified algorithm would be:

- choose two limits: `a = log(0.5)/log(max(values))` and `b = log(0.5)/log(max(values))`
- calculating with `a` as power gives a mean lower (or equal) to 0.5
- calculating with `b` as power gives a mean higher (or equal) to 0.5
- choose a value `m` somewhere in the middle and calculate the mean with `m` as power; if that mean is lower than 0.5, `m` should replace `a`, otherwise `m` should replace `b`
- repeat the previous step until either the mean is close enough to 0.5, or `a` and `b` get too close to each other